# JSON arrays compact syntax

Tags: arrays, json

As i understand it, a typical JSON array could be something like this:

```
{ "measurements":[ {"order":1, "time":"23:55:12.234", "value":3.4543235}, 
                   {"order":2, "time":"23:55:14.118", "value":3.9785742}, 
                   {"order":3, "time":"23:55:15.942", "value":3.6892639}]
}
```

But since i have several hundred measurements, i would like to remove the repeating keys like this:

**1:**

```
{ "measurements":[ 1, "23:55:12.234", 3.4543235, 
                   2, "23:55:14.118", 3.9785742, 
                   3, "23:55:15.942", 3.6892639]
}
```

And if i do it like that i also would like to keep the keys for reference - to allow other sequences and maybe even additional information in the array, i could imagine something like this:

**2:**

```
{ "measurements":{"assembly":"order,time,value",
                  "values": [ 1, "23:55:12.234", 3.4543235, 
                              2, "23:55:14.118", 3.9785742, 
                              3, "23:55:15.942", 3.6892639]
                 }
}
```

Are 1 and or 2 correct JSON and if not is there another way?

And even if that is allowed - is there a more sensible / common way of doing this?

Comment: if you want to validate a format, use a resource like **[jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com)**.

Comment: Alright - thanks. The mentioned link suggests thst it is syntactically right - i was thinking that. But i wonder because i am mixing strings and numbers here. That's what unsettles me.

@Paul Crovella: I'n aware that i can zip everything. Just let's assume there can be reasons for not doing so.